# Linq filter using a List

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a `LINQ` where clause where it should satisfy the condition of multiple records.

For example, in the `Animal` table. I have 3 columns

> Id, Name, age

I need to find all `Animals` where the Name is an `array`. `['Ant', 'Mouse', 'Turtle']`

```
var aniList=   db.Animals.Where(c => 
    c.Name== arrAni[0]  ||
    c.Name== arrAni[1] ||
    c.Name== arrAni[2]   );
```

However, the above is hardcoded. I need to directly insert the List into the where clause so it gets filtered out. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could simply use Linq `.Contains` method:

```
var aniList = db.Animals.Where(c => arrAni.Contains(c.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_)

```
string[] animalNames = new string[] {"ant", "mouse", "turtle"}
var desiredAnimals = animalList
    .Where(animal => animalNames.Contains(animal.Name));
```

In words: from the collection of `Animals` in `animalList`, keep only those `Animals` whose `Name` is in the collection of `AnimalNames`